How to add extra space/margin below tabbar iOS Swift

I have attached the reference image to provide a clear idea of what I want to do. How can I add left, right, and bottom spacing to the tab bar and also make it rounded? Thanks in advance.
How do i make the rounded tab.
  self.tabBar.backgroundColor = .navyBlue
  self.tabBar.layer.cornerRadius = self.tabBar.frame.height/2

I tried setting the background image of the tabbar, but I couldn't get the bottom space of the tabbar.

You practically have to make a custom view that looks like that, from scratch, and put it in the appropriate place. The built-in UITabBar (I assume this is what you are using) doesn't support this.

Thanks for responding to me.
Yes, I am using the built-in UITabbar.

No, you don't. The built-in UITabBar does not look like this.

I know that the built-in UITabBar won't look like this, but my question is how can I implement this? :)

Don't use the UITabBar, and make a custom View with buttons maybe?

Do you have any reference demo?

I'm using below method for UITabBar height. It is an overridden method of UITabBar. Using below method you can change size of tabbar.
override open func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    let window = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window
    let bottomPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
    // Adjust the height of the tab bar
    var sizeThatFits = super.sizeThatFits(size)
    sizeThatFits.height = 65 + bottomPadding
    return sizeThatFits
}

